# I can't force powershell to correctly enconde saved emails

Tags: regex, email, powershell, encoding

I have saved (Thunderbird) around 2000 emails which I want to analyse.
So I created a loop through all emails read them one by one into one variable:

```
   #several tries to read the email - they all fail
   #$mail = [IO.File]::ReadAllText(".\$($_.Value)", System.Text.Encoding.Unicode) #ERROR
   #$mail = [IO.File]::ReadAllText(".\$($_.Value)")  # match fails
   $mail = (Get-Content -Encoding UTF8 ".\$($_.Value)") # match fails too
   $mail = $mail.Replace('ä','ae') # no error, no replacement :(
```

and then I first want to match several German dates like: "Montag, den 2. März 2009" (=Monday March 2, 2009)

```
   #                    Montag               2          M        ärz       2009
   if ( $mail -match '.+[MDF][a-z]+.+?den.*?(\d+).*?([JFMAJSOND][a-z]+).*?(\d+)' ) {
```

The match fails due to the German ä. :(

- I tried various version to load the file (s.a.).
- I tried $mail.Replace("ä","ae") and got an Error no replacement.
- I tried to enter the ä in the match-pattern [äa-z]+ and failed
- I loaded the email into my Notepad where the ä is correctly displayed and Encoding is Ansi
- If I print $email to the console and 'März' (and the other öüß) is converted into: 'M�rz'

Due to the fact that I have to deal with English and German months I created a hash to replace the month-name by its number and then to parse the date - so match is only one problem, parsing would be the next one.

What do I have to do to either
- convert März to Maerz or
- match correctly März or 
- read the emails with the correct coding
for a smooth match and parse of:

```
    $h = @{März = 3; Maerz = 3}
    $date = "Montag, den 2. März 2009"
    if ( $date -match 'den.+?(\d+).*?([JFMASOND][a-zäöü]+).*?(\d+)' ) {
        $tmp = "$($Matches[1]) $($h.$($Matches[2])) $($Matches[3])"
        try{
           $day = [datetime]::ParseExact( $tmp, "d M yyyy", $null)
        } catch { Write-Host "Error Parse" $tmp}
    } else { Write-Host "Error match" }
```

Thanks in advance

Found a strange solution:

```
    $mail = [IO.File]::ReadAllText(".\$($_.Value)")
    ...
    $h = @{März = 3; Maerz = 3; 'M�rz' = 3}
    $date = "Montag, den 2. März 2009"
    if ( $date -match 'den.+?(\d+).*?([JFMASOND][a-z�]+).*?(\d+)' ) {
        $tmp = "$($Matches[1]) $($h.$($Matches[2])) $($Matches[3])"
        try{
           $day = [datetime]::ParseExact( $tmp, "d M yyyy", $null)
        } catch { Write-Host "Error Parse" $tmp}
    } else { Write-Host "Error match" }
```

Not very nice, but working at least for matching and parsing the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the german ä use:

```
\p{L}
```

This will match all Unicode Letters. (Upper and Lower case)

---

This regex matches: Montag, den 2. März 2009

```
.*[MDF][a-z]+.+?den.*?(\d+).*?([JFMAJSOND][\p{L}]+).*?(\d+)
```

---

This should match some german dates of the format you mentioned above like: Montag, den 2. März 2009

```
(?:Montag|Dienstag|Mittwoch|Donnerstag|Freitag|Samstag|Sonntag),\s+den\s+\d+\.\s+(?:Jannuar|J(?:ä|&auml;)nner|Februar|Feber|M(?:ä|&auml;)rz|April|Mai|Juni|Juli|August|September|Oktober|November|Dezember)\s+\d{4}
```

---

This works in my Powershell:

```
$test = "Montag, den 2. März 2009"
$test -match '(?:Montag|Dienstag|Mittwoch|Donnerstag|Freitag|Samstag|Sonntag),\s+den\s+\d+\.\s+(?:Jannuar|J(?:ä|&auml;)nner|Februar|Feber|M(?:ä|&auml;)rz|April|Mai|Juni|Juli|August|September|Oktober|November|Dezember)\s+\d{4}'
```

Comment: Thank you! I have found in my email one other März you can enter in your match-string: M&auml;rz ;) Have a nice weekend